# Array out of bound in Java

Tags: java, arrays

**I am trying to count the number of each character from a to z in a random array of chars of size 100**.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz";
        String[] countc = new String[26];
        char[] charArray = new char[100];
        for(int i = 1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            charArray[i-1]=chars.charAt(r.nextInt(chars.length()));

            System.out.print(chars.charAt(r.nextInt(chars.length())));
            if(i%20==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(charArray.length);
        int m = 0;
        int p=0;
        for(int n = 0;n<100;n++)
        {
            char xx = chars.charAt(n);
            m = 0;
            p=0;
            do
            {
                if(charArray[m]==xx)
                {
                    p=p+1;

                }
                m=m+1;
            }while(m<=charArray.length);
            countc[n]=""+p+""+xx;
        }
        System.out.println("The count of each character is "+ countc);
    }                   
}
```

Comment: I am getting error at line "if(charArray[m]==xx)" says array index out of bound.

Comment: Debug As > Java Application

Comment: The line char xx = chars.charAt(n) should fail when n > 26, since chars is only 26 chars long, and n goes up to 100.

Answer (score 1):

`> for(int n = 0;n<100;n++)`

should be

```
for (int n =0; n<99; n++)
```

`charArray = 0 to 99 (i-1)`, but subroutine below you are going 0 to 100 `(int n)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
m<=charArray.length
```

To this:

```
m<charArray.length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    /* ... */
}while(m<=charArray.length);
```

On the last iteration, `m` will be equal to `charArray.length`, so when you call `charArray[m]`, it'll be out of bounds. Change it to `while(m < charArray.length);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

char xx = chars.charAt(n); is getting called all the way up to 99 when chars.charAt() can take a max argument of 25. You need to fix your loop logic so that you check all 100 elements for each of the 26 possible characters, not the other way around.

EDIT: Same thing is happening on your do..while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `String chars` is omitting the 's' so I've added it in and updated the code to work slightly differently.

After creating the `charArray` it iterates over each character 26 times (once for each letter). There's probably a much better way to do this but I'm not so hot on Java.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RandomChars {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();
    String chars= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";//added the 's'?
    String[] countc = new String[26];
    char[] charArray = new char[100];
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        charArray[i]=chars.charAt(r.nextInt(chars.length()));
        System.out.print(charArray[i]);
        if((i+1)%20==0){
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    for(int n=0; n<26; n++){//for each of the 26 chars
        char xx = (char)chars.charAt(n);
        int p=0;

        for(int a=0; a<100; a++){//loop through the charArray and count the matches
            if(charArray[a]==xx){
                p++;
            }
         }

         countc[n]=""+xx+":"+p;
    }
    System.out.println("The count of each character is "+Arrays.toString(countc));

  }
}
```

http://runnable.com/VCRLPa-2kdoqq2dW/stackoverflow-com-questions-26042877-for-java